# Why FMX TListView on scrollbox lags on Android?

Tags: android, delphi, scroll, firemonkey, tlistview

Is here any way to avoid lag on Android when populated TListview on scrollbox goes away from screen and comes back ? It looks like it trying to repopulate all items in list before appearing on screen.

Sample code: ScrollBox1 - alligned 'Client', ListView1 on ScrollBox1, Button1 on ScrollBox1;

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LItem: TListViewItem;
  I: Integer;
begin
  //just...
  ListView1.Height := ListView1.ItemAppearance.ItemHeight;
  ListView1.Position.X := 0;
  ListView1.Position.Y := 0;

  // To achieve the best performance use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate.
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 1 to 3000 do
    begin
      LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
      LItem.Text := IntToStr(I);
    end;
  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
  end;

  //expand form
  Button1.Position.X := 1000;
  Button1.Position.Y := 1000;
end;
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. To avoid this ugly behavior I had to use a TTask and notify the update to the user with a Label like 'loading...' . Maybe not the best but it worked.

Comment: I can avoid it by checking ScrollBox viewport position OnViewportPositionChange and hiding or showing ListView if it is almost offscreen, but such solution looks not professional.